# Permalink to the last page of a thread in phpBB

Tags: phpbb

A Question from the user side, rather then the admins.

Is there a way to bookmark or link to a thread and make phpBB always show the last page of the thread, regardless of how many pages long the thread actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of phpbb 3.0.12 I haven't found any officially documented way but the following might do the trick:

```
xxx/viewtopic.php?f=yy&t=zzz&start=50000
```

where only the **start=50000** is important. the f and t parameters are to determine the subforum and the thread, the start parameter determines the post in the thread. Setting the value of the start parameter to a ridiculously high value seems to trigger phpbb to show the last page.

Comment: D'oh. How come I didnt think of trying that?

Answer (score 3):

I found it helpful to hover an unread-topic-icon. I saw:

```
xyz/viewtopic.php?t=123&view=newest
```

As Trilarion mentioned before, parameter t determines the topic. `view=newest` is the necessary part

**Edit**
For clarification: I saw it on a phpbb 2.0 board.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, you have to retrieve how many pages there are first.

Answer (score 0):

instead of...
phpBB2/index.php?threads/very-interesting-thread-you-cant-stop-looking-at/page-58

do...
phpBB2/index.php?threads/very-interesting-thread-you-cant-stop-looking-at/latest